# Add MsSQL via PHP INI

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I just uploaded and overwrote the old php.ini with a new one that was blank and now all my mssql_connect() functions are not working.

What is the commange to enable this again?

Comment: There isn't a command that will just rewrite the config for you. You could try reinstalling PHP, or digging through the source code for a default config to get you started

Comment: I'm surprised only this function not working. Any particular reason for having done so?

Comment: You might want to clarify if you're asking a) how to enable SQL Server support in php.ini, or b) how to recover a php.ini file that you accidentally overwrote. FWIW, text configuration files are good candidates for keeping under source control, which also provides a kind of backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the semi-colons `;` before the modules for mssql.

Search for `;extension=php_mssql.dll` in your php.ini and remove the `;` at the beginning. After this, restart the Apache service.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you'll have to assemble a new php.ini. You can go to http://php.net/downloads.php and download PHP as if you were going to install it. There are at least two version there to start with.

Answer (score 0):

In php for windows are a precomiped php_mssql.dll, in unix/linux you can use mssql module via freetds library, some distributions have compiled it if not you have to compile it manually. if you have doubts about compile ask it in comments.

To enable or disable modules in php ini search the `extension` keys you look something like

In Unix/Lin:ux

```
extension=mssql.so
```

In windows

```
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

disabled means the line is not present, or can be commented with a semicolon `;` at first.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP distribution on most platforms ships with sample `php.ini` files named `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`. If you copy whichever one of these files is most suitable for your environment to `php.ini`, you will at least be in a known good state.